# ngFor in a third-party compoment goes in loop

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm developing an angular webApp, using some third-party components to display data.
In this specific case, I'm using a component that can display multiple series of points in a single chart object.

This is my code:

```
<div class="e-panel-header">
    <h6>{{Widget.Properties.Title}}</h6>
</div>
<div class="e-panel-content d-flex" [ngStyle]="{'width': width, 'height': height}">
    <ejs-chart #chart id="chart-container" [primaryXAxis]='primaryXAxis' [width]="width"> 
        <e-series-collection>         
            <e-series *ngFor="let serie of Values; let i = index" [dataSource]="serue.DetailValues" type="Line" xName="DateTime" yName="Value" name={{serie.Id}}>
            </e-series>          
        </e-series-collection>
    </ejs-chart>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I try to create a series using the `*ngFor` directive, cycling the array where I've stored all my data, it goes in a loop and the browser (firefox) give me a nice

```
ERROR InternalError: too much recursion
_loop ej2-base.es2015.js:166
_loop ej2-base.es2015.js:165
extend ej2-base.es2015.js:160
_loop ej2-base.es2015.js:184
_loop ej2-base.es2015.js:165
extend ej2-base.es2015.js:160
_loop ej2-base.es2015.js:178
_loop ej2-base.es2015.js:165
extend ej2-base.es2015.js:160
```

Obviously, if I create the `<e-series>` component manually for each element of values, everything works fine.

What can be the problem? It makes me mad.

Answer (score 0):

the error code says, that your Maximum call stack size exceeded, it might happen because you are calling two or more recursion function, try warping the ngFor like this
`<ng-container *ngFor="let serie of Values; let i = index"[dataSource]="serue.DetailValues"> <e-series  type="Line" xName="DateTime" yName="Value" name={{serie.Id}}> </e-series> </ng-container>`

Comment: I tried just now. No changes, the application behaves exactly the same.